# How to solve symbolically a nonlinear equation system using sympy with Python

Tags: python, math, sympy, symbolic-math

I am trying to solve a pair of non-linear equations composed of the terms (a,b,r,f). I want to solve for a,b and have the terms r,f as parameters of the resulting solution. I read the tutorials regarding the use of the nonlinsolve command. I wrote the following code. I am studying engineering so sorry for the ''dirty code''

```
import sympy as sym
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
from sympy.core.relational import Eq
from sympy import log  
from sympy.solvers.solveset import nonlinsolve, solveset
#def variable
r,f,a,b=sym.symbols('r f a b')

#big terms
alpha=(1+(a-b*f-b*r)**2)**(1/2)
beta=(1+(a-b*f-b)**2)**(1/2)
gamma=(1+(a-b*f)**2)**(1/2)
delta=(1+(a+b)**2)**(1/2)
epsilon=(a**2+1)**(1/2)
zeta=(1+(a-b*r-b)**2)**(1/2)

#resolution
system = [((epsilon-gamma)/b)+((alpha-beta)/b)-((epsilon-delta)/b) ,log((a-b*f-b*r+alpha)/(a-b*r-b+zeta))+log((a+epsilon)/(a-b*f+gamma))/b-log((a+epsilon)/(a-b+(1+(a-b)**2)**(1/2)))/b]
vars = [a,b]
print(nonlinsolve(system, vars))
```

and I get the following output that I do not understand at all.  I was expecting to have a tuple of the 2 resulting solutions for a and b.

```
ConditionSet((a, b), Eq((a**2 + 2*a*b + b**2 + 1)**0.5 - (a**2 - 2*a*b*f + b**2*f**2 + 1)**0.5 - (a**2 - 2*a*b*f - 2*a*b + b**2*f**2 + 2*b**2*f + b**2 + 1)**0.5 + (a**2 - 2*a*b*f - 2*a*b*r + b**2*f**2 + 2*b**2*f*r + b**2*r**2 + 1)**0.5, 0) & Eq(b*log((a - b*f - b*r + ((a - b*f - b*r)**2 + 1)**0.5)/(a - b*r - b + ((a - b*r - b)**2 + 1)**0.5)) - log((a + (a**2 + 1)**0.5)/(a - b + ((a - b)**2 + 1)**0.5)) + log((a + (a**2 + 1)**0.5)/(a - b*f + ((a - b*f)**2 + 1)**0.5)), 0), ProductSet(Complexes, Complexes))
```

How can I solve my equation ? The problem I am working on is supposed to have a know solution, I have been told that a basic rootfinder was supposed to be able to solve my system.

Comment: From past experience I can tell that sympy is not very powerful and when it fails to solve it simply spits out the same problem as a solution.

Comment: I don't know who told you that a "basic root finder" would solve your system but the equations have a symbolic parameter `f` meaning that no numeric root finder can possibly work unless you choose a value for `f`.

Comment: If you substitute values for `f` and `r` then you can use `nsolve`. This system of equations has too high a degree to have any analytic solution using ordinary functions. That's a basic mathematical limitation rather than a limitation of SymPy (see the Abel-Ruffini theorem).

Comment: As a side note, sympy gets very confused with floats. And Python changes `1/2` to the float `0.5`. It is recommended to change that to `sym.S(1)/2`  or to `sym.Rational(1,2)` (or use `sym.sqrt()` here). It further is recommended not to use the `math`, `scipy` or similar libraries mixed with sympy code.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin the author of the paper I am working with claims that he solved the equation using Mathematica's ''FindRoot” command. I don't own a license for it so I figured I can just use python.

Comment: From your comments, if I get it right, I clearly overestimated the computational limits of sympy ? I can set values for 'r' it would not be a problem. But I absolutely need to have a,b as functions of f. I am looking for a(f) and b(f) to plot them. I also read about the Abel-Ruffini theorem. If I understand correctly, as it is right now my pair of equations are unsolvable using common methods.

What do you think of the following method : I will solve the pair of equations for 1000 values of 'f' comprised in [0,1]. With the 1000 values of a,b I will make 2 scatter plots of a(f) ,b(f) ,f∈[0,1]

Comment: Mathematica's FindRoot function finds approximate numerical solutions. The equivalent in SymPy is `nsolve`. To use either `FindRoot` or `nsolve` you need to substitute values for any symbols other than the unknowns.